# My elements changing their place when i try to position other element

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.a {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.b {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.c {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.newsbox {
  border-style: solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 40%;
  margin: 50px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="a">About</li>
    <li class="b">Lore</li>
    <li class="c">Home</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="newsbox">

</div>
```

When i try to position newsbox element to bottom right my ul li elements moving with newsbox too how can i stabilize the positions of ul li elements to stay at their place

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi im trying to position my newsbox div to bottom right but when i try to do it my ul li elements changing their place too with newsbox div but i dont want them to move

Comment: That just repeats the question which is still unclear. What is this supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you want newsbox bottom right fixed on the page:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.a {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.b {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.c {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.newsbox {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  display:block;
  /* add the lines above*/
  
  border-style: solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 40%;
  margin: 50px 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="a">About</li>
    <li class="b">Lore</li>
    <li class="c">Home</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="newsbox">

</div>
```

Add this if you want the newsbox just under the menu bottom right (not fixed):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.a {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.b {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.c {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.newsbox {
  position: absolute;
right: 0;
  /* add the lines above*/
  
  border-style: solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 40%;
  margin: 50px 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="a">About</li>
    <li class="b">Lore</li>
    <li class="c">Home</li>
  </ul>

</div>
  <br>

<div class="newsbox">

</div>
```